# How to add multiple custom control button leaflet js?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, custom-controls

I found the code to add a single button on the leaftlet map to the topleft corner. But now I want to add multiple buttons one after another.

1. Is it possible to insert multiple buttons inside the following code?
2. I also have tried to use checkbox/radio buttons. But I dont know how to add labels to the checkbox and button.
3. And add checked/unchecked properties for them.

Thanks.

My Code here:

```
var customControl = L.Control.extend({ options: {position: 'topleft'},onAdd: function (map) {
var container = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'leaflet-bar leaflet-control leaflet-control-custom');

onAdd: function (map) {
    var container = L.DomUtil.create('input','my-button btn');
    container.type="button";
    container.title="x";
    container.value = "x";
    container.label = "x";

    container.style.backgroundColor = 'white';     

    container.style.backgroundSize = "30px 30px";
    container.style.width = '40px';
    container.style.height = '40px';
    container.style.borderRadius = "25px";
    container.style.padding = "0";
    container.style.margin = "10px";

container.onclick = function(){
  console.log('buttonClicked');
}

return container;}});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create as many Leaflet "controls" as you wish. You can insert them at any corner, and they will simply "stack up" (with a 10px margin if I remember correctly) in a vertical column in the given corner.

As for the content of each control, it is purely HTML and CSS. In your code you are using Leaflet's utility `L.DomUtil.create()`, but you could have also simply used the native `document.createElement()` (but would have to add the class in a separate line) or even jQuery DOM utility (with which you can directly write an HTML string).

Then you can build complex content (with inputs, associated labels, etc.). Just look for HTML tutorials / JavaScript that build DOM nodes.

Comment: Yup. A good example of this is the `Leaflet.draw` plugin which adds toolbar buttons stacked on top of each other for drawing points, polygons, circles, etc.